# Event when input value changes

Tags: php, dynamic, input, onchange

Hello, I want a popup when the value of my input changes. I tried this, my test of my input :

```
<input onchange="maFonction()" id="result" readonly="readonly" type="text" value="0" size = "10" />
```

my function

```
maFonction = function(){
$.post("yourFile.php");
}
```

yourfile.php

```
<?php

$a = 40 ;
if ($result > $a) {
    ?>
    <script> alert("yay!"); </script> 
     <?php } elseif ($result == $a) {
     ?>
                    <input onclick="s(this.form);" type="button" value="sauvegarder" /> 
        <?php
        } else {
    ?>
    <script> alert("boooo!"); </script> 
    <?php
}




?>
```

I explain the readonly : it is like a calculator : I have many (7) inputs, I can stock values and the readonly is the total. So I need a msg when it is under 40, when it is equal, and when it is over 40.

Thanks for help cause for the moment I don't have any error I just have the popup boo when my page refreshes after nothing.

Comment: there are many wrongs in what you do. The main problem from where I see it is that you don't seem to understand the basics of AJAX. Your aren't supposed to return HTML or javascript that way, although it could work at some point. Actually, for what you want, you absolutely don't need AJAX nor server-side code...

Comment: @Bartdude do you have a exemple of correction or what I need to change?

Comment: Well there are quite a few problems, but let me build a fiddle for you... I'll come back with it :-) Is jQuery OK or do you need Vanilla JS ?

Comment: I'm here to learn and understand the easier or the better will be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my remark, you don't need server-side code to do this. [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eFBC6/) to do it with jQuery. Very easy :

HTML :

```
<input type="text" id="myInput"/>
```

Javascript (supposing you included jQuery) :

```
$('document').ready(function() {
   $('#myInput').on('change',function(){
       if(isNaN(this.value))
           alert("Please enter a number");
        else
        {
            var a = 40;
            var myNumber = parseInt(this.value);
            if(myNumber > a) alert("yay!");
            else if (myNumber == a) alert("equals!");
            else alert("boooo!");
        }
    }); 
});
```

I think the code is quite easy to understand. Note that you have to leave the text field for the "change" event to trigger, and it supposes you actually changed something. You could use `blur` event if you want to trigger each time and not only when value changed.

If you want or need to do that kind of check server-side (it may not be that easy than comparing 2 numbers), you can indeed use AJAX. But in that case I would advise to return XML , JSON or even an unformatted string from your server-side code, and treat the response in javascript. For example, you could return simply 'bigger', 'smaller','equal' , and act accordingly in the `success` event of your AJAX call. But that's for another lesson ;-)

EDIT following remark of OP :

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="input1" /><br/>
<input type="text" id="input2" /><br/>
<input type="text" id="input3" /><br/>
<input type="text" id="myInput" readonly="readonly"/>
```

Javascript :

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    $('#input1,#input2,#input3').each(function()   {$(this).on('change',recalculate);}
       );

});

function recalculate()
{
    if(isNaN(this.value))
       alert("Please enter a number");
    else
    {
        var a = 40;
        var value1 = $('#input1').val().trim() == "" ? 0 :  parseInt($('#input1').val());
        var value2 = $('#input2').val().trim() == "" ? 0 :  parseInt($('#input2').val());
        var value3 = $('#input3').val().trim() == "" ? 0 :  parseInt($('#input3').val());
        var total =  value1 + value2 + value3
        $('#myInput').val(total);
        if(total > a) alert("yay!");
        else if (total == a) alert("equals!");
        else alert("boooo!");
    }
}
```

[The fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eFBC6/1/)

And if you wish to calculate and alert only when all 3 fields have been filled :

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    $('#input1,#input2,#input3').each(function()   {$(this).on('change',recalculate);}
       );

});

function recalculate()
{
    if(isNaN(this.value))
       alert("Please enter a number");
    else
    {
        if($('#input1').val().trim() !== "" && $('#input2').val().trim() !== "" && $('#input3').val().trim() !== "")
        {
            var a = 40;
            var value1 = $('#input1').val().trim() == "" ? 0 :  parseInt($('#input1').val());
            var value2 = $('#input2').val().trim() == "" ? 0 :  parseInt($('#input2').val());
            var value3 = $('#input3').val().trim() == "" ? 0 :  parseInt($('#input3').val());
            var total =  value1 + value2 + value3
            $('#myInput').val(total);
            if(total > a) alert("yay!");
            else if (total == a) alert("equals!");
            else alert("boooo!");
        }
    }
}
```

[The fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eFBC6/2/)

Comment: doest work. My input is readonly is a result of an equation of many input like input1 + input2 = input3 and I want my input3 if a number appear or change to have a message. if input1 = 20 + input2 = 10 my input3 = 30 dynamicly and 30 is under 40 so msg : boo! .

Comment: Well no bif deal but how was I supposed to guess that ? I admit I didn't see the readonly, but you example doesn't reflect your needs... cfr my edit then, more in line with your needs, at least a good source of inspiration.

Comment: Not guessing but i explained after my code sorry if i was not clear. That why I need help, could you help me?

Comment: My bad, I missed that. Cfr my edit. As I said, it may not be 100% what you need, but it's anyway a better start than what you had before.

Comment: It's work exactly want I want but one question : how do I popup one time and not generate 2x or more ?

Comment: Well, it depends WHEN you want to popup exactly. I presume you would want to wait that the 3 inputs are filled before calculating (and popping up) anything, right ? in that case you could add one more condition before calculationg total and performing the rest of the code.

Comment: if it's possible that sound great.